# Unable to install nodejs in ubuntu v-20.04.1

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install nodejs version 14.15.4 using this command-

```
apt install nodejs=14.15.4
```

But I am getting this error-
E: Version '14.15.4' for 'nodejs' was not found

Which mistake I am doing in this command?

Or any better way to install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way (from my experience) has always been using [node version manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), as it allows you to switch between node.js versions easily.
To begin, make sure you're up to date:
`sudo apt update`.

Install NVM first using *either* cURL or wget using one of the following:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

We then need to load NVM, which can be done with:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Then, use `nvm install 14.15.4`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But I am waiting to get more answers.

Comment: I have not get any exact answer. So I have use this method. Thanks @PiggyPlex.

Comment: I'm not sure why directly downloading it doesn't work. And as for the last command, `nvm install` is just the command from node version manager used to install. I've always had to use NVM as using apt to install has never worked for me.

Comment: No clue. I have this on an automated script which I got from their Github. Apologies there. In essence, it looks as if it just locates and opens the nvm.sh file.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

To install Node.js v14.x in Ubuntu 20.04

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - 

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```